# Merge tab delimited files one upon other without header

Tags: shell, awk

Hi I have two tab delimited text files

file.1.txt

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    4204560 4204560 T   C
chr1    9471179 9471181 ATA -
chr1    9471230 9471230 A   C
chr1    9471247 9471247 T   C
chr1    9471254 9471254 C   A
chr1    9471261 9471262 AA  -
chr1    9471262 9471262 A   C
```

AND file.2.txt

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    9471268 9471268 -   ACT
chr1    9471274 9471274 A   C
chr1    9471275 9471275 A   C
chr1    9471284 9471284 T   C
chr1    9471297 9471297 T   C
chr1    9471302 9471302 T   C
chr1    9471312 9471312 A   C
```

Now if I want to combine these two files in such a way that second file's header row is excluded and files are combined one upon other

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    4204560 4204560 T   C
chr1    9471179 9471181 ATA -
chr1    9471230 9471230 A   C
chr1    9471247 9471247 T   C
chr1    9471254 9471254 C   A
chr1    9471261 9471262 AA  -
chr1    9471262 9471262 A   C
chr1    9471268 9471268 -   ACT
chr1    9471274 9471274 A   C
chr1    9471275 9471275 A   C
chr1    9471284 9471284 T   C
chr1    9471297 9471297 T   C
chr1    9471302 9471302 T   C
chr1    9471312 9471312 A   C
```

How to do this using awk command or shell script?

P.S. Number of columns in actual files are 168.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may also help you on same too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{print;next} FNR!=NR && FNR>1{print}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

OR more precisely no need of `FNR!=NR`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{print;next} FNR>1{print}' file1.txt file2.tx
```

Comment: @RonicK, glad that it worked for you. You could thank some one by up-voting the answer and could select any of the answer as correct one too for the good of other readers too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 || NR == 1' file1 file2
```

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    4204560 4204560 T   C
chr1    9471179 9471181 ATA -
chr1    9471230 9471230 A   C
chr1    9471247 9471247 T   C
chr1    9471254 9471254 C   A
chr1    9471261 9471262 AA  -
chr1    9471262 9471262 A   C
chr1    9471268 9471268 -   ACT
chr1    9471274 9471274 A   C
chr1    9471275 9471275 A   C
chr1    9471284 9471284 T   C
chr1    9471297 9471297 T   C
chr1    9471302 9471302 T   C
chr1    9471312 9471312 A   C
```

Or else using just `cat` and `tail`:

```
cat file1; tail -n +2 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
$ awk 'p<FNR;{p=FNR}' file1 file2
```

outputs:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt
chr1    4204560 4204560 T   C
chr1    9471179 9471181 ATA -
chr1    9471230 9471230 A   C
chr1    9471247 9471247 T   C
chr1    9471254 9471254 C   A
chr1    9471261 9471262 AA  -
chr1    9471262 9471262 A   C
chr1    9471268 9471268 -   ACT
chr1    9471274 9471274 A   C
chr1    9471275 9471275 A   C
chr1    9471284 9471284 T   C
chr1    9471297 9471297 T   C
chr1    9471302 9471302 T   C
chr1    9471312 9471312 A   C
```

ie. output if previous `FNR` `p` is less than current.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to just do:

```
cat file1; tail +2 file2
```